# get result on join table in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i'm quite new in ruby. i want to get result from join table but the result that i get the table itself

```
Table A
id | user_id | cat_id
1      1        2
2      2        3
3      1        1
4      1        3
5      3        4

class A < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cat, optional: true
end
```

```
Table cat
id | name
1      ai 
2      bi 
3      ci 
4      di
5      ei

class Cat < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :a
end
```

i want to show all cat that associate to specific user_id on table A

***A.where(user_id: 1).joins(:cat)***

but the result that i get is

```
[{
   id: 1,
   user_id: 1,
   cat_id: 2
},{
   id: 3,
   user_id: 1,
   cat_id: 1
},{
   id: 4,
   user_id: 1,
   cat_id: 3
}]
```

the expected result:
array of product based on Table A with user_id 1

```
[{
   id: 2,
   name: bi
},{
   id: 1,
   name: ai
},{
   id: 3,
   name: ci
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the `cat`, you must start from there:

```
Cat.joins(:<plural_version_of_table_a>).where(<plural_version_of_table_a>: { user_id: 1 })
```

Comment: it gives me result #<Cat::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fdf81d1112c>

Comment: Probably is an error. Inspect that object. See what it says.

Comment: yes, i make a mistake in cat model, i should use `has_many: as`. thanks